# Trouble with critical exponents

Tags: statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena

I want to show that

> $$\frac{\langle S_iS_j\rangle}{\langle S_i\rangle^2}\rightarrow 0$$
>   in the ferromagnetic phase for dimension $d\geq 4$.

My problem is the following:
I know that
$$\frac{\langle S_iS_j\rangle}{\langle S_i\rangle^2}\sim\frac{G(\xi)}{m^2}$$
where $G(\xi)\sim\frac{1}{\xi^{d-2+\eta}}$, $\xi\sim|t|^{-\nu}$, $m\sim|t|^\beta$.
In the mean field approximation, we have $\eta=0$, $\nu=1/2$ and $\beta=(d/2-1)/2$. Plugging these in gives
$$\frac{\langle S_iS_j\rangle}{\langle S_i\rangle^2}\sim\frac{1}{(|t|^{-\nu})^{d-2+\eta}}|t|^{-2\beta}=\frac{1}{|t|^{-(d-2)/2}}\frac{1}{|t|^{d/2-1}}=1$$
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is merely an answer, but a bit long for a comment.
In the MFA, short-range spin correlations are simply $⟨S_iS_j⟩=⟨S_i⟩⟨S_j⟩=m^2$, so this is trivial. I think there might be an error somewhere. We want to know if we can actually use the mean field approximation.

In the mean field approximation, you want the fluctuations to be smaller than the approximation you are making: $G_{fluct}<<G_{MF}$.
$$
G'(\xi)=\frac{G_{fluct}(\xi)}{G_{MF}(\xi)}\rightarrow0
$$
Since the size of the fluctuation is of the order of the correlation length $\xi$ (this is how the correlation length is defined), the free energy of a typical fluctuation per unit volume is proportional to $G_{fluct}\sim\xi^{-d}\sim|t|^{\nu d}$. On the other hand, the singular part of the mean-field free energy is governed by the specific-heat exponent $\eta$: $G_{MF}\sim|t|^{2-\eta}$. Regrouping everything, you then have
$$
{G'(\xi)}\sim|t|^{\nu d-2+\eta}
$$
Then for the Ising model, $\eta=0$ and $\nu=1/2$:
$$
\lim_{|t|\rightarrow0}G'(\xi)=\lim_{|t|\rightarrow0}|t|^{ d/2-2}=0
$$
For this to be true, the exponent must be bigger then $0$
$$
\implies d>4.
$$
So the mean field approximation is true whenever $d>4$. So in your case, you can use this approximation. But it also means that my previous statement is true, that is: $⟨S_iS_j⟩=⟨S_i⟩⟨S_j⟩=m^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I don't see why $G_{MF}\sim|t|^{2-\eta}$. My notes say $G_{MF}\sim|t|^{2-\eta-d}$

Comment: It comes from two integrations of the specific heat over temperature.